# Ruby OpenSSL Install on Mac 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

Using brew I go though the normal install process to get rbenv and Ruby installed.
Everything goes smoothly but it is soon apparent Ruby did not install with openssl onboard.

The only thing that seems to allow rbenv to auto install openssl during the ruby install is to use this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
```

Is this a bug in rbenv or brew that needs fixing?

Comment: What part did Homebrew play when installing rbenv and Ruby? You shouldn't use it to install either of those because rbenv should be installed from [the github source](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), and, once it's installed, rbenv can be used to install Ruby. Homebrew *could* be used to install prerequisites for Ruby, but you shouldn't have to link anything afterwards.

Comment: brew installed rbenv and openssl

Answer (score 0):

There's a long thread about `rbenv` with openssl on Github [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/377)

The easiest way to fix it are:

1) Update to the latest version of `rbenv` where they fixed the `CONFIGURE_OPTS` options, then delete and re-build all your ruby versions.

2) Use the older version of rbenv and explictly set the CONFIGURE_OPTS to use the brew openssl:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install <whatever version you need>
```