# "Unable to require openssl" when trying to install ruby gems on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rubygems, bundler

Since I upgraded to OS X 10.10 Yosemite, I get the following error when trying to install a ruby gem:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

But when I do `which openssl` it shows me the path:

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled rvm and ruby but still get the same error.

How do I install Ruby gems?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639691/ruby-openssl-install-on-mac-10-10-yosemite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336573/unable-to-require-openssl-install-openssl-and-rebuild-ruby-preferred-or-use-n)

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL issues with Ruby on Yosemite could be a result of your installed version of Ruby trying to locate OpenSSL certificates in `/etc/openssl/certs` instead of its new location at `/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs`. Try [reinstalling ruby using the `--disable-binary` switch](http://toadle.me/2015/04/16/fixing-failing-ssl-verification-with-rvm.html) so that the source is re-built on your local machine instead of using the pre-compiled binary. For example:

```
rvm uninstall 2.2.0
rvm install 2.2.0 --disable-binary
```

Comment: This was the solution for me @jdeleon

Comment: It looks like RVM now checks for this - it output "Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date..."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gem installer can't find your openssl.

Try this with your ruby version:

```
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.3.4 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```